# PHP Foreach with keys inside Foreach without keys

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops

I have a parent foreach loop without keys surrounding a child foreach loop with keys. Everything for the parent loop code works fine alone. And everything for the child loop code works fine alone when used outside of a nested loop. However once I put the child loop inside the parent loop, it breaks the page from everything below that point.

Could it be that I'm using keys in the foreach child?

```
$months = array(
    '01'=>'January',
    '02'=>'February',
    '03'=>'March',
    '04'=>'April',
    '05'=>'May',
    '06'=>'June',
    '07'=>'July',
    '08'=>'August',
    '09'=>'September',
    '10'=>'October',
    '11'=>'November',
    '12'=>'December'
);

foreach($resT as $row):
  foreach ($months as $key=>$value) {   
    $selected = '';
    if( $key == $theMonth) : $selected = ' selected=\"selected\"'; endif;
    '<option value="' . $key . '"'.$selected.'>' . $value . '</option>';
  }
endforeach;
```

Comment: what is $resT structure and what is expected result?

Comment: the syntax for this is ALL over the place ... lol

Comment: What's this line for `'<option value="' . $key . '"'.$selected.'>' . $value . '</option>';`  missing `echo` ?

Comment: what relationship does the outer loop `$row` have to the inner loop, and where does `$theMonth` come from?

Comment: Well, I guess first the question is: does it matter that I have foreach loops with the parent not having a key, while the child does?  If it doesn't, then I know that I need to dig further.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: it doesn't matter.  My flaw was elsewhere in the code, as I was not resuming my output variable in the proper places. Thanks for the views though.